# C# using System.Data.Metadata.Edm

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to use EntityType class, but I get an error when I try to use it. I did some digging and it appears I need to use this System.Data.Metadata.Edm.

I tried this...

`using System.Data.`

and I enter the . Metadata does not appear as an option....any suggestions

I am new at this.

I am using .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: have you ever found a solution? I have the same issue for .net 4.0. System.Data.Entity.dll is referenced, but "using System.Data.Metadata.Edm;" doesn't work.

Answer (score 17):

if you use EF6, you should using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add the reference System.Data.Entity.dll.

You can also check which assembly is need to some class in msdn

For example, for the EntityType:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.entitytype.aspx

And you will see there the information about the assembly:

> Assembly:  System.Data.Entity (in System.Data.Entity.dll)

Comment: I add the reference, but it still does not show MetaData or Entity or anything. Do I have to restart the program?

Comment: how do I find that out? When I say I am new, I mean new new

Comment: Ok, you need to give us some more information. How did you add the reference? By using the "Add reference..." option? What are you trying to do with it? I believe it should work also on 3.5, but the link I gave you was based on version 4.0.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have referenced `System.Data.Entity.dll` in your project.

Comment: I add the reference, but it still does not show MetaData or Entity or anything. Do I have to restart the program?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EF6, then you need to add a reference to System.Data.Entity.dll

After than you must include the namespace System.Data.Entity.Core

Basically, from EF6 all classes in System.Data have been moved to System.Data.Entity.Core.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following namespace if you are upgrading from EF5 to EF6
Replace System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity with
System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity, need not change anything else apart from above because it solves my problem